# Google maps Places API : Update response when required

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

need help with Google Maps Places API.
So I am trying to build an app which might require update the google maps response based on setting from business.

For example: Lets say a user search for nearby Thai restaurant. Now, Google maps will return all restaurants based on user location. What I really need is to update the results with restaraunt which is OPEN only.

Is there a way I can get JSON response from API, update it based on settings in my app (for example business which are available) and then display the updated results on map?

Comment: The Place Details result includes a field opening_hours which contains a boolean value open_now, indicating if a place is open at the current time. https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsResults

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the **openNow** parameter of your Nearby Search to *true*. The following snippet shows how you can build your request in client side.

Notice that I put the coordinates of *'Sydney'* as the center and the radius of the nearby search was set to *500 meters*. I set openNow to *true*, put the value '*Thai Restaurant'* in the name where it should be the term to be matched against the names of places and set the type to *'restaurant'*. Here is the [sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/qus2tevz/) showing how it works.

```
var sydney = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.867, 151.195);

var map = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById('map'), {center: sydney, zoom: 15});

  var request = {
    location: sydney,
    radius: 500,
    openNow: true,
    name: "Thai Restaurant",
    type: "restaurant",
  };

var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  service.nearbySearch(request, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        createMarker(results[i]);
      }

      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    }
  });
```